# Using MVC architecture. Visualforce page unable to get list column from Model

Tags: apex, javascript, controller, wrapper-class

I created an MVC software architecture. Here's the breakdown:
M= Model_Enter_Discount
V=Page_Enter_Discount
C=Controller_Enter_Discount.

On my Model_Enter_Discount page, I have created the following 3 lists:

```
    public void createDifferentProductLists(String quoteID)
    {
        public List<productWrapper> nonDiscountableList = new List<productWrapper>();
        public List<productWrapper> supportDiscountList = new List<productWrapper>();
        public List<productWrapper> productDiscountList = new List<productWrapper>();
        List<QuoteLineItem> quoteLineItemList=[Select ID,Discount,Product_Code__c,Quantity,PricebookEntryId,QuoteId,Discounted_Unit_Price__c FROM QuoteLineItem Where QuoteId=:quoteID];    
        }
        List<PricebookEntry> priceBookEntryList = [SELECT ID,NAME,PRODUCT2ID,UNITPRICE FROM PricebookEntry Where ID in: PricebookEntryIDx]; 
        }
        List<Product2> product2List = [SELECT ID,NAME,DISCOUNTABLE__C,PRODUCTCODE FROM PRODUCT2 WHERE ID IN:Product2Idx];

        productWrapper fullProductList = new productWrapper();
        for(QuoteLineItem QLI: quoteLineItemList){
            fullProductList.QLTID = QLI.ID;
            fullProductList.Product_Code = QLI.Product_Code__c;
            fullProductList.Quantity = QLI.Quantity;
                fullProductList.Product2Id = PBE.Product2Id;
            fullProductList.UnitPrice = PBE.UnitPrice;
            fullProductList.Discountable = P2.Discountable__c;
        }   
        if(fullProductList.Discountable == 'No'){
            nonDiscountableList.add(fullProductList);
        }       
        else
            if(fullProductList.Product_Code.startsWith('SV')){
                serviceDiscountList.add(fullProductList);
                }
            }       
        else 
            productDiscountList.add(fullProductList);
            }                       
    }
```

As you can see, I use a wrapper class(name of wrapper class is productWrapper) to take fields from QuoteLineItems,PricebookEntry and Product2 to create 3 new lists.

Then, on my controller which is Controller_Enter_Discount, I call each of these lists. For this example, I'll be calling the productDiscountList.

```
 discountUtility = new Model_Quote_Discount();
public List<Model_Quote_Discount.productWrapper> getProductDiscountList()
{   
    return discountUtility.productDiscountList();
}
```

Finally, on my visualforce page, I want to output a datatable with the contents of the productDiscountList.

```
    <apex:dataTable align="left" value="{!productDiscountList}" var="quo" >
      <apex:column headervalue="Quantity" value="{!quo.Quantity}"/>
      <apex:column headervalue="Product Code" value="{!quo.Product_Code}"/>
    </apex:dataTable>
```

### Visualforce then gives me an error saying Unknown property: Model_Enter_Discount.productwrapper.Quantity. Why is the Visualforce page unable to access the Quantity column on the list that I created on the Model side?

Wrapper class code as requested:

```
    public class productWrapper 
    {
        ID QLTID {get;set;}//QuoteLineItemlist ID
        Double Discount{get;set;}//QuoteLineItem Discount
        String Product_Code{get;set;}//QuoteLineItem ProductCode
        Decimal Quantity{get;set;}// QuoteLineItem Quantity
        ID PricebookEntryID{get;set;}// QuoteLineItem PricebookEntryId
        ID Product2Id{get;set;}//PricebookEntryList Product2Id
        Double UnitPrice{get;set;}// PricebookEntryList UnitPrice
        String ProductName{get;set;}// Product2List Name
        String Discountable{get;set;} //Product2List Discountable

/** Class:public class productWrapper 
        * Input:         
        * Ouput:        
        * Purpose:  
**/     
        public productWrapper()
        {
            this.QLTID=QLTID;
            this.Discount=Discount;
            this.Product_Code=Product_Code;
            this.Quantity=Quantity;
            this.PricebookEntryID=PricebookEntryId;
            this.Product2Id=Product2Id;
            this.UnitPrice=UnitPrice;
            this.ProductName=ProductName;
            this.Discountable=Discountable;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post your wrapper class? I think the issue is in there.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the post with the wrapper class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your Wrapper class, the variables are not PUBLIC, any external class will not see the variables as visible.

The changes are below:

```
        Public ID QLTID {get;set;}//QuoteLineItemlist ID
        Public Double Discount{get;set;}//QuoteLineItem Discount
        Public String Product_Code{get;set;}//QuoteLineItem ProductCode
        Public Decimal Quantity{get;set;}// QuoteLineItem Quantity
        Public ID PricebookEntryID{get;set;}// QuoteLineItem PricebookEntryId
        Public ID Product2Id{get;set;}//PricebookEntryList Product2Id
        Public Double UnitPrice{get;set;}// PricebookEntryList UnitPrice
        Public String ProductName{get;set;}// Product2List Name
        Public String Discountable{get;set;} //Product2List Discountable
```

Hope this helps.